# Calculate the RowCount in DataGrid in VB Scripts using Test Complete Tool

Tags: web-applications, vbscript, automation, testcomplete

Im assigned to write the scripts for Automating a Web Application in VB Scripts using Test Complete Tool. In my application, I have to delete a data and have to check after deleting that whether the deleted data exists on the datagrid or not. How can I do it. I tried doing that by calculating the RowCount of the Datagrid. But, since there is no RowCount Property for the DataGrid in Test Complete, I cant find the solution. Please help me with this to find the RowCount.

Thanks In Advance.,

Comment: You'll likely have better luck asking this on the [TestComplete forums](http://smartbear.com/forums/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For supported grid controls, you can use wRowCount:
http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/14601/

In case of an unsupported grid in an [Open Application](http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11462/), you can use the grid control's native properties and methods availble to TestComplete (check the Object Browser to see the list). You may need to ask your Dev Team about what exact properties/methods to use in your test to accomplish a specific task.

Also, in case of an unsupported gird, don't forget to vote for it in the feature survey :)
http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing/survey/

Comment: I've already got the answer from a friend of mine., Thank u., We can get the rowcount by capturing any column of the grid and from the result properties, click the Parent button in the properties window that shows the grid ctrl properties. From there we can get the rowcount of the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Grid classname should xxxGrid not xxxGridSite.
Because rowcount properties are available only xxxGrid classname.